# Order a list of elements with another list of doubles

Tags: c#

I'm working with the Revit API and I have two lists, one of Elements and other of Doubles, these doubles are extracted from the pointXYZ where these elements are positioned on the Z axis.
I need to order the elements list using the double list, and need to work with other lists like curves, points.

I tried OrderBy but can't understand how work with the other list as a key to the first one.

As an example:

```cs
List<Elements> listElements = {ele1, ele2, ele3, ele4}
List<double> listDouble = {4.25, 3.2, 5.2, 2.0}
```

I need a output like:

```cs
List<Elements> newListElements = {ele4, ele2, ele1, ele3}
```

Comment: The following will yield 3,1,0,2 which is the order of the new elements : List<int> order = listDouble.Select((x, i) => new { num = x, index = i }).OrderBy(x => x.num).Select(x => x.index).ToList();

Comment: Is your values `listDouble` in are distinct?

Comment: Thanks jdweng, this will help. Not everyone, in a case of a square shape the top line would have a unique double, the two sides a equal one and the bottom a unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Dictionary That way

```
Dictionary<Elements, double> dic = new Dictionary<Elements, double>();
for (int i = 0; i < listDouble.Count; i++)
{
dic.Add(listElements[i],listDouble[i]);
}
var newListElements=dic.OrderBy(x => x.Value).Select(x=>x.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to understand how to use dictionarys and your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Zip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8) method to combine the values with their sort key. When combined you can sort them as usual with `OrderBy()` and pick the value back from the zipped entries via `Select()`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IList<string> values = new List<string> { "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno" };
    IList<double> sort = new List<double> { 3.4, 5.6, -2.4, 7.5, 1.3 };

    IList<string> sortedValues = values
        .Zip(sort, (v, s) => new {v, s}) // combine...
        .OrderBy(it => it.s)             //           ...sort...
        .Select(it => it.v)              //                     ...extract
        .ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", values));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", sort));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", sortedValues));
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
abc, def, ghi, jkl, mno
3.4, 5.6, -2.4, 7.5, 1.3
ghi, mno, abc, def, jkl
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [Array.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.8) method overloads.

```
string[] listElements = { "ele1", "ele2", "ele3", "ele4" };
double[] listDouble = { 4.25, 3.2, 5.2, 2.0 };

Array.Sort(listDouble, listElements);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", listElements)); // ele4, ele2, ele1, ele3
```

Comment: Thanks, this will help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I found a better way to sort the list of items without having to use a dictionary.

This method sorts from left to right, top to bottom.
Hope this can help you.

```
public static List<Element> SortLeftRightTopBottom(List<Element> list)
{
    // Sort the list by XYZ left to right, top to bottom
    list = list.OrderByDescending(pos => (pos.Location as LocationPoint).Point.Y)
               .ThenBy(pos => (pos.Location as LocationPoint).Point.X).ToList();

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution! Thank you!